# Getting type error: "takes exactly 1 arguments, given 6" in Django when using a function that does take 6 positional args

Tags: python, django, typeerror

The error msg:

> meli_publicar() takes exactly 1 argument (6 given)

My function meli_publicar:

```
def meli_publicar(titulo,pvp,categoria,tapa,descripcion,access_token):
    meli = Meli(client_id=ID_NUMBER,client_secret=SECRET)
    body = {"condition":"new", "warranty":"Ante cualquier falla de impresión o de encuadernación se cambia por otro igual sin cargo.", "currency_id":"ARS", "accepts_mercadopago":True, "shipping":{"local_pick_up":True}, "description":descripcion, "video_id":'', "listing_type_id":"bronze", "title":titulo, "available_quantity":1, "price":pvp, "buying_mode":"buy_it_now", "non_mercado_pago_payment_methods":[{"id":"MLAMO"},{"id":"MLATB"}],"category_id":categoria, "automatic_relist":True, "pictures":[{"source":tapa}]}
    response = meli.post("/items", body, {'access_token':access_token})
    respuesta = json.loads(response.content)
    return respuesta
```

I use this function in models.py, inside a function used with a post_save signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=EjLibro)
def meli_publicar(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', True):
        access_token = meli_obtenerToken()
        tapa = 'http://www.site/images/1.jpg'
        respuesta = meli_publicar('A title',100,'MLA40490',tapa,'<h1>Título</h1>',access_token)
```

I don't understand where is the error, because meli_publicar() takes 6 args, not 1.

*Django 1.8.4, Python 2.7*

Comment: Are you sure that the error message relates to the first function? As you have two functions with the same name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the name `meli_publicar` with the function your are decorating.

Don't use name **`meli_publicar`** name twice.

```
def meli_publicar(titulo,pvp,categoria,tapa,descripcion,access_token):
    ...

@receiver(post_save, sender=EjLibro)
def meli_publicar_signal(sender, **kwargs) # use different name
    ...
    respuesta = meli_publicar('A title',100,'MLA40490',tapa,'<h1>Título</h1>',access_token)
```

Comment: Of Course! I have to sleep 8 hours at least. Thank you!

Comment: @Thesauros Please mark it as correct answer if it helps